# iOS - SiriKit - Add custom command without INUIAddVoiceShortcutButton

Tags: ios, swift, siri, sirikit, sirishortcuts

I would like to add Siri command for my application. I know that for this I have to add Siri Shortcuts with custom Intents. Usually tutorials include `INUIAddVoiceShortcutButton` which presents an `INUIAddVoiceShortcutViewController` which walks the user through steps to add the Siri Shortcut.

In my application it would be inconvenient to use the above mentioned button and controller, and I would like to add commands just by installing (or opening the app or in any other way but not by pressing a button and presenting the default controller).

Is it possible to add Shortcuts for voice commands like this **without** the `INUIAddVoiceShortcutButton` and the `INUIAddVoiceShortcutViewController`?